# How to reinstall an intermediary version from source?

Tags: installation, freebsd

I am trying to create a test server that is vulnerable to the Heartbleed attack.  I installed apache24; the problem is twofold:
- FreeBSD comes with OpenSSL 0.9.8( not vulnerable )
- if I install using the ports, I'll get the latest version of OpenSSL( not vulnerable )

I have the tar from the OpenSSL site for version 1.0.1f( vulnerable ), but I'm wondering how to install it on my FreeBSD virtual machine.

Requirements for check:
- please tell me how to uninstall the included-by-default version( 0.9.8 )
- please tell me how to install OpenSSL 1.0.1f afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to build a **FreeBSD** test server vulnerable to *heartbleed*:

1. **Installing FreeBSD 10.0**

   *FreeBSD* 9.x and 8.x are coming with *OpenSSL* 0.9.x. On the other hand, the base release **FreeBSD 10.0** comes with **OpenSSL 1.0.1e**. So it might be easier to get a 10.0 release, install it and a few packages: you'll have a test server in hours if not minutes.

   - [get *FreeBSD* 10.0 base release](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/ISO-IMAGES/10.0/)
   - [installing *FreeBSD* 9.x and later](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/bsdinstall.html)
2. **Installing a custom OpenSSL** with **apache24 using it**

   Regarding *FreeBSD* < 10.0, there is no real point in removing the included-by-default version of *OpenSSL* from the base system, as you just have to make your *apache24* install point toward your private openssl-1.0.1f install.

   - get the OpenSSL 1.0.1f (or earlier) sources from the [official *OpenSSL* site](https://www.openssl.org/source/)
   - be sure to have `perl` installed, as it is needed to build *OpenSSL*
   - build a custom *OpenSSL* (to install in `/usr/local` as the ports would do):

     ```
     # sh ./config --prefix=/usr/local
     # make
     # make install
     ```

   **Be aware** that this is a custom install without any trace or log for the package management tools.

   - create/add to your `/etc/make.conf` the following line:

     ```
     WITH_OPENSSL_PORTS=yes
     ```
   - then install or re-install the other modules (`devel/apr1`, `www/apache24`, ...)
   - you can check the *libssl* used by *apache24* (in fact the apache24 *mod_ssl* module):

     ```
     # ldd /usr/local/libexec/apache24/mod_ssl.so |grep ssl 
     /usr/local/libexec/apache24/mod_ssl.so:
             libssl.so.8 => /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.8 (0x801634000)
     ```

     The apache24 *mod_ssl* is now using the custom *OpenSSL* library from `/usr/local`.

---

As stated in (2): this is not necessary to make a vulnerable FreeBSD test system and it is an extremely time consuming task, particularly for people not familiar with the procedure.

- **Removing the default *OpenSSL* from base system** (un-necessary)

  To really remove *OpenSSL* from the base system, you need to rebuild it and you will loose *openSSH* and *Kerberos* (and maybe some others). This is a really long process and you should follow [the official procedure](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/makeworld.html) carefully.

  - [Get your system sources](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/svn.html) (from install or through subversion)
  - create your `/etc/src.conf` with following line (to know more: [`man src.conf`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?src.conf)):

    ```
    WITHOUT_OPENSSL=yes
    ```
  - rebuild the base system (you might need to rebuild the kernel if the sources are not in-sync with your current system version), in short: `make buildworld` and `make installworld` ([more information here](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/makeworld.html)).

  You might need to clean the *OpenSSL* files manually.

Comment: Your answer is *godly*, so thanks; I had not even considered install FreeBSD 10.0, so that seems like the easiest way.

Comment: It took me a while to put all down, but I just did that sort of things for years and it was painful watch you struggling ;)